# Getting error of : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen all stack overflow question about this but can't find solution.
Getting error at this line.

```
String p_score = player_score_US.getText().toString();
```

My code

```
public class UpdateScore_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    private DatabaseReference root=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("A_matches&Score&contest").child("1").child("Score");
    private us_adapter usAdapter;
    private TextView playerName;
    private Button SaveScorebtn;
    public ArrayList<us_model> list1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.updatescore);
        recyclerView2=findViewById(R.id.recycleview2);
        SaveScorebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.us_saveScore);
        EditText player_score_US=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.us_Player_Score12);
        playerName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Player_Name);

        list1=new ArrayList<>();
        usAdapter=new us_adapter(this,list1);
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(usAdapter);
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    String name1 = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                    us_model myModel=new us_model(name1);
                    list1.add(myModel);
                }
                usAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(UpdateScore_activity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        SaveScorebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String p_score = player_score_US.getText().toString();
                HashMap<String, String> usermap = new HashMap<>();
                usermap.put("Score",p_score);
                for (int i=1;i<4;i++){
                    root.child(String.valueOf(i)).setValue(usermap);
                }
                openMain();
            }
        });
    }}
```

Layout file of update Score Activity(Recyclerview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Match_Name"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Update Score"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000002"
                android:textSize="32dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="456dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycleview2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="441dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/us_saveScore"
                android:layout_width="127dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="62pt"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
                android:background="#FF80AB"
                android:text="Save Score"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout file of player card

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#A6D673">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Player_Name"
            android:layout_width="256dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Player Name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/us_Player_Score12"
            android:layout_width="79dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:hint="Enter"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter class

```
public class us_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<us_adapter.Myviewholder> {

    ArrayList<us_model> mlist1;
    Context context;

    public us_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<us_model> mlist1){
        this.context=context;
        this.mlist1=mlist1;
    }

    public us_adapter.Myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.updatescore_row,parent,false);
        return new Myviewholder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Myviewholder holder, int position) {
        us_model model1 =mlist1.get(position);
        holder.Name.setText(model1.getName());
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return mlist1.size();
    }

    public class Myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView Name;
        Button update;

        public Myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Player_Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Model class

```
public class us_model{
    private String Name;

    public us_model(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions that you could try for this problem.

Solution 1:

From

```
EditText player_score_US=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.us_Player_Score12);
```

To

```
final EditText player_score_US=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.us_Player_Score12);
```

The reason is, if two methods see the same local variable in Java, Java wants you to ensure you will not change it, In that case you have to make it `final`.

Solution 2:

As well as, you could make it a `global variable`.

```
public class UpdateScore_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView2;
private DatabaseReference root=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("A_matches&Score&contest").child("1").child("Score");
private us_adapter usAdapter;
private TextView playerName;
private Button SaveScorebtn;
private EditText player_score_US;
public ArrayList<us_model> list1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.updatescore);
    recyclerView2=findViewById(R.id.recycleview2);
    SaveScorebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.us_saveScore);
    player_score_US=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.us_Player_Score12);
    playerName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Player_Name);

    list1=new ArrayList<>();
    usAdapter=new us_adapter(this,list1);
    recyclerView2.setAdapter(usAdapter);
    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                String name1 = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                us_model myModel=new us_model(name1);
                list1.add(myModel);
            }
            usAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(UpdateScore_activity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    SaveScorebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String p_score = player_score_US.getText().toString();
            HashMap<String, String> usermap = new HashMap<>();
            usermap.put("Score",p_score);
            for (int i=1;i<4;i++){
                root.child(String.valueOf(i)).setValue(usermap);
            }
            openMain();
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: I tried both of your solutions , but still I am getting that error. Any other thing that I should try?

Comment: @SahilNasariwala, could you add layout file here to check it?

Comment: Added my xml,adapter and model class file.

Comment: @SahilNasariwala, Did you get the error when click the button?

Comment: Yes i get the error when i press save score button.

Comment: @SahilNasariwala, could you add the layout file of UpdateScore_activity?